# Is there significant risk in not keeping a theme updated?

Tags: themes, security

Is there significant risk in not keeping a theme updated?

We have various themes which we have purchased and modified. It would be a lot of work to install theme updates and re-implement our changes. Do themes, not kept updated, pose a significant security risk?

Comment: this is way too broad. what does it mean "significant", what kind of updates have been done to the theme by you and by the author/ It is just impossible to give any more specific answer than "it depends"

Comment: @MarkKaplun there may be some general rule of thumb. The answer has been helpful in quantifying the risk.

Comment: if you are in a position in which it is hard to upgrade to new versions, than you have done it wrong and the only cure is to put an effort to solve this, regardless if it is a "significant" risk or no risk at all

Comment: @MarkKaplun it's risk vs reward. If the client won't pay for the work then we have to recommend we keep a backup, and use some hacking defence such as caching and disabling php, cloudflare, etc.

Comment: than it is a different answer between a blog and a commerce site. not sure how you expect to get an helpful answer here

Comment: @MarkKaplun the answers were useful. If everybody unanimously threw up their arms in outrage, or gave first-hand experience of being caught out I would know to lean more heavily on our client to spend the money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking outdated plugins are more of a risk, but themes should be updated.

The "heavier" the theme (more javascript, custom functions etc) the more likely it is to become a risk when out of date. Frankly it's one good reason to code lean/mean themes yourself and not buy of the shelf, but that's just my opinion.

The answer to your question then, yes is "It's a risk". But I wouldn't not go as far as as saying "significant" (as opposed to the plugins)

Comment: a little complement to this answer : themes purpose is to display then they should not have security risk for the server. unfortunately, some badly-thinked themes include lots of code which process datas and this code can have lots of security problems and need to be updated

Comment: @mmm - Yes thank for that clarification, completely right. Some of the "larger" themes these days a full of such code, in an attempt to be "all things to all people" :(

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a risk.  There is a risk to just having a site online.  Having outdated software increases that risk.

If the theme designer is no longer updating you can still run the site, but this is what I would suggest and a "lazyperson" option (believe me, no insult intended there.  I guess i could say "easy way out".)

Back everything up, often.  If your site does get hacked because of old code, which chances are it will as the code gets older and older, restore a backup.

Start the update process then, or get someone to do it with/for you, with a new theme.